# steam-installer having trouble

Tags: package-management, dependencies, steam

Having trouble installing steam, after getting user password in sudo prompt it has an

```
error: pkgProblemResolver::Resolve lead to breaking packages. This can be caused by fixed packages.
```

It's whining about `libgl1-mesa-dri:i386`, `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386` and `teamviewer`. I can't install the libgl1*:i386 because they will downgrade amd64 versions of themselves to 19.* and i need them to stay at 20.* because i plan on using obs-studio and with mesa 19.* it triggers earlyoom (basically it overflows RAM).
Is there a way to install those two libgl1 packages without breaking anything?

Comment: Also the only PPA i've added after upgrading from 18.04.4 to 19.10 is kxstudio's, before upgrading i removed the folder  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

Comment: The answer may be `lxd` but I'm not sure about that yet. Steam there launched successfully. Don't yet know how to work with folder links outside the container.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, lxd is the answer. Followed those steps: [tutorial](https://blog.simos.info/running-steam-in-a-lxd-system-container/)